# How to add SPFx webpart to page in SharePoint online sub-sites?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepointframework

I have created the SPFx web part for custom development in SharePoint online modern site.
I have created multiple subsites under one site collection. I need to add the SPFx web part to all sub-sites.
I have tried to save a template of one site but it doesn't allow me to save the site as a template. It has thrown me the below error,

> Sorry, this site can't be saved as a template. It contains apps that
> don't work in templates: spfx-demo-client-side-solution

***I have tried another way. I have created a site to add all necessary lists, libraries, and pages. I have successfully saved the template for that site. I have created many subsites using that custom template.***

Now, I need to add my SPFx web part to the sites that were created using a template.

For that, I need to add the SPFx app to all subsite's Site Contents and add the SPFx web part to all subsite's Site Pages. Can I achieve that with PowerShell or do I need to prefer some alternative way?

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks in Advance.